# php's FINALLY is for Uncaught exception?

Tags: php, finally

For what is can see, the only difference between putting code inside `finally` block and outside `finally` block is that the code inside `finally` block will be executed when if there is an uncaught exception while code after try-catch-block that is not inside finally-block will not be executed. am i correct or there are more differences?

Comment: Study **Exception handling** thoroughly properly for correct concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`finally` is code you want your try block to execute no matter what (when an exception is thrown, when an exception is not thrown, and even when your block has a return statement executed).

Comment: nice. i did't know you cant `return` from a page. is there more situations when it can be useful beside Unsought exceptions and return statements?

Comment: Those are the two situations when you would want to include a `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

> am i correct

Yes.

> or there are more differences?

Nope!